# How to check if a Tensorflow Lite Tensor has dynamic or static size, what about HasDynamicTensorImpl

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Regarding [this issue on Tensorflow's github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48199), I have been advised to add a print in the `HasDynamicTensorImpl` function. Unfortunately, I can not find relevant documentation on this function. Does anyone know how it works or does anyone know how to check if there are dynamic-sized tensors in a graph?

(I already checked every shape and they are well defined as you can see if you visualize the model in [netron](https://netron.app/))

Answer (score -1):

There are two cases that are categorized as dynamic:

(1) The given shape has dynamic dimensions or
(2) The given tensor type is dynamic based one, e.g, string, resource and variant types.